# How do I change "First Name Last Name" to "Last Name, First Name" using code in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

The data is located in the salesreps table and the column I need rearrange is Name. I need to rearrange the name column by creating sub-strings. Any and all help is wanted. Thank you!

Comment: [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html). Or better, use the application code. Please include some sample data and expected results to quantify the set of responses. What have you tried? Happy to help, but doing it for you is asking too much.

Comment: Are you trying to change the table or do a query that sorts the data?

Answer (score 1):

In general, your requirement could actually be very complex/impossible if either the first or last name could consist of more than one word.  Consider the following two names:

```
Jean Luc Picard
Jean-Claude Van Damme
```

In the first case, `Jean Luc` is a two word first name, while in the second case, `Van Damme` is a two word last name.

That being said, under the assumption that each first and last name would always be just a single word, then `SUBSTRING_INDEX` can handle your requirement:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Name = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', -1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1));
```